# WMesh face shading artifacts in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, visualization, mesh, vtk

I'm using OpenCV v4.4.0 with gcc v10.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.5. This code snippet:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::viz;
......
vector<Vec3f> points{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}};
vector<int>   faces{4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1};
Viz3d         window("Mesh");
WMesh         mesh(points, faces);

window.setBackgroundColor(Color::gray());
mesh.setColor(Color::indigo());
mesh.setRenderingProperty(OPACITY, 0.4);
mesh.setRenderingProperty(SHADING, SHADING_FLAT);
mesh.setRenderingProperty(REPRESENTATION, REPRESENTATION_SURFACE);
window.showWidget("mesh", mesh);
window.spin();
```

creates and displays this planar mesh:

[image]

The square on the left is defined as 2 triangles and is shaded uniformly, but the square on the right, which is defined as a single quadrilateral face is not shaded uniformly. Again, the mesh is planar. Why the non-uniformity?

It becomes even more non-uniform when I change shading from `SHADING_FLAT` to `SHADING_GOURAUD`:

[image]

Can someone explain what is going on here? I know that quadrilateral faces are converted to triangles, but why the shading is non-uniform?

**EDIT**

As noted by Матвей Вислоух in his answer below, I intended to use:

```
vector<int> faces{3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5, 2};
```

which properly defines two triangular and one quadrilateral face. This solves the problem of artifacts in the left half, but they still remain in the right half:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> faces{3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 2, 5};
```

There is a specific rule how opencv unpacks indices from polygon.

if there is a polygon : (5, 1, 4, 5, 2, 0) it consists of 3 triangles: (1,4,5) , (4, 5, 2), (5, 2, 0)

OLD:

vector   faces{4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 0, 2, 3, 0, 5, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1};

This means you draw 3 polygons: 2 quads and 1 pentagon.

But by indices I guess that you want to draw 2 triangles, and one quad, so try this:

vector   faces{3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 5, 2};

Comment: You are right. I was following a misleading example found somewhere on the web. Triangles are now free of a diagonal artifact, but the quadrilateral face still has one.

Comment: You can try to invert the order of vertices in polygons. You have clockwise order, but it should be counterclockwise, it is a standard.

Comment: `faces{3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1};` produces the same artifacts.